# How do I use regexp-match in Racket to only include the number with decimals

Tags: racket

Let's say i'm given a string

```
"<span class='price'>6.86</span>"
```

How can I use regexp-match in order to show "6.86" without knowing the size of the number, or the number used.

So, it could be "x.xx", "xx.xx", "xxx.xx", and so on.

Comment: Regular expressions are usually not the best ways to parse HTML. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(define elm "<span class='price'>6.86</span>")
(regexp-match "<span class='price'>([0-9.]*)</span>" elm)
```

Ouput:

```
'("<span class='price'>6.86</span>" "6.86")
```

Comment: Perhaps better to use `#px"\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"` since `[0-9.]*`  matches empty values as well as `.3.2.3.`

Answer (score 0):

my version:

```
(regexp-match #rx"<span class='price'>([0-9]*\\.*[0-9]*)</span>" 
              "<span class='price'>6.86</span>")

'("<span class='price'>6.86</span>" "6.86")
```